# Flex box collapses, throwing boxes next to each other, i.s.o. masonry

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently working on a project and i'm stuck at using flex

http://dennisprins.nl/mvdw/index.php

All looks fine, but when you make your viewport smaller (around 1400px) you see that the column layout collapses. How can i prevent them from collapsing. There is no media query present in my css, so it isn't due to media queries.

The placeholder with all boxes:

```
#overview {  

    -webkit-box-flex: 4;
    -moz-box-flex: 4;
    -webkit-flex: 4;
    -ms-flex: 4;
    flex: 4;


    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;

    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    height: 100vw;
}
```

The individual box:

```
.video_grid {
    background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(239,239,239,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(239,239,239,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(239,239,239,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(239,239,239,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(239,239,239,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(239,239,239,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#efefef',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    margin: 0.5em 0em;
    width: 20em;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing some old Flexbox properties that are obsolete with the new Flexbox properties. The old prefixed properties are still recognised by their respective browsers and this causes unexpected behaviour.

`-webkit-box-flex: 4;` and the similar `-box-*` properties need to be **removed**.

- [Here is a quick guide to recognising the old flexbox properties:](http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/)

  > If you are looking at a blog post (or whatever) about Flexbox and you
  >   see `display: box;` or a property that is `box-{*}`, you are looking at
  >   the old 2009 version of Flexbox.
  >
  > If you are looking at a blog post (or whatever) about Flexbox and you
  >   see `display: flexbox;` or the `flex()` function, you are looking at an
  >   awkward tweener phase in 2011.
  >
  > If you are looking at a blog post (or whatever) about Flexbox and you
  >   see `display: flex;` and `flex-{*}` properties, you are looking at the
  >   current (as of this writing) specification.
- [Use this as a guide to all the properties you *should* be using.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [Here is the browser compatibility for the current Flexbox recommendation](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox). Only the `-webkit-` prefix is required for the Safari browser.

I noticed that you have made some changes on your site, this example is based on the snippet in your question.

Use this:

```
#overview {  
    -webkit-flex: 4;
    flex: 4;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    height: 100vw;
}
```